# Replacing Functions in a sympy expression with a Symbol of the same name

Tags: sympy

It seems that sympy's `solve` function cannot solve some equations when `Function`s are present in the equations or are the targets to solve for.

To get around this, I'd like to create a generic function that will automatically replace `Function`s in an expression with `Symbol`s of the same name.

For example, if `Function('myfunc')(Symbol('t'))` appears in an expression, I'd like to substitute `Symbol('myfunc')` in for that.

The `subs` function cannot do this because the names must be explicitly known beforehand.

The `replace` function looks promising, particularly the func -> func flavor of it, but I cannot figure out how to get the name of a function object from the object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```py
import sympy
    
t = sympy.Symbol("t")
x = sympy.Symbol("x")
F = sympy.Function("F")(t)
G = sympy.Function("G")

def remove_undefineds(expression):
    for item in sympy.preorder_traversal(expression):
        if isinstance(item, sympy.function.AppliedUndef):
            name = str(item).split('(')[0]
            expression = expression.subs(item, sympy.Symbol(name))
    return expression
     
        
expression = F + G(x) + t**x
 
cleaned = remove_undefineds(expression)
```

yields:

```
    In [1]: expression
    Out[1]: t**x + F(t) + G(x)

    In [2]: cleaned
    Out[2]: F + G + t**x
```

The idea is to loop over preorder_traversal of the expression, check for each item whether it's an instance of AppliedUndefined (i.e. F(_) with F being an undefined function), and if yes, replace it with a symbol of according name.

I used string split to get the "myfunc" part alone, assuming the arguments shall be dropped at this step; else one could replace just by `str(item)`.

I also assume only undefind functions are to be replaced, else one would have to augment accordingly...